# Is there an equivalent to the Javascript function .closest() in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html-table, repeater

The tables on the site I'm using are being created by repeaters, therefore I don't know how to identify them once the page is generated. I need to be able to select a row based on a button click from a cell in that row.

There is a Javascript function to do this but I'd like to replicate in .net (C#);

```
currentRow = $(evt).closest("tr");
```

The table is generated like this; (the last column containing the "hide" button)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="StoredProcedureRepeater" runat="server">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <tr ID="HideMe" class="NotHidden" runat="Server">
                            <td style="width: 300px" runat="server">
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# StoredProcedure.Caption %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Url.StoredProcedure(StoredProcedure) %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td runat="server">
                                <%# StoredProcedure.Description %>
                            </td>
                            <td runat="server">
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="EditProcedure" runat="server" Text='edit' NavigateUrl='<%# Url.EditProcedure(StoredProcedure) %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td id="HideBtn">
                                <asp:button ID="HideUnhide" runat="server" image="../images/collapse.png"  onclick="Hide_Unhide"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:Repeater>
```

Behind code for the repeater; (So for clarity, this repeater is created whilst inside another.)

```
private void SchemaRepeater_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Schema = (Schema)e.Item.DataItem;

        var storedProcedureRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("StoredProcedureRepeater");

        storedProcedureRepeater.ItemCreated += StoredProcedureRepeater_ItemCreated;
        storedProcedureRepeater.DataSource = _schemaStoredProcedures[Schema];
        storedProcedureRepeater.DataBind();
    } 
 private void PriorityProcedureRepeater_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        StoredProcedure = (StoredProcedure)e.Item.DataItem;
    }
```

Comment: I bet you use Webforms, show your code that renders table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you want to replicate this in C#, I assume you mean you want to do this server-side.

First, you need to specify an event handler for the RepeaterItemCommand in your markup.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCommand="MyRepeater_ItemCommand" ... />
```

Then in your codebehind, you define the event handler.

```
protected void MyRepeater_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
}
```

The RepeaterCommandEventArgs contain information about the row that caused the event, including the data item that was used to build the row.  If you built your repeater off of a List, then your event handler would look something like this:

```
protected void MyRepeater_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var dataItem = (Widget)e.Item.DataItem; // <-- this is the dataitem for the row
    int dateItemID = dataItem.ID; // You can access the properties on your data item to "do stuff"
}
```

Comment: This seems like it might be helpful. Although I can only see the ID of the repeater itself, I can't see the row that the button was clicked on (am using quick watch). The DataItem is actually null.

Comment: How are you binding the repeater?

Comment: It's a little contrived. I didn't write the original myself (typical). I'll add to the main question...

Comment: You need to add another event handler for the StoredProcedureRepeater.ItemCommand event:

storedProcedureRepeater.ItemCommand += StoredProcedureRepeater_ItemCommand;

When you click the button in your child repeater, your event handler should fire.  That is where you want to try and access the DataItem.  If the child repeater's event isn't firing, or the DataItem is null, then you want to set some breakpoints in your different events to see what order they are firing in, as it is possible that the handlers are firing in the wrong order.

Comment: It seems the root of the problem is that the DataItem will be null during postbacks. So the data needs re-retrieving. This is causing problems unrelated to this issue so will hunt down that solution elsewhere.

Comment: That is correct.  The data is not persisted between postbacks.  If the amount of data is small, then you can manually store the data collection in the viewstate and rebind the controls on page load.  I've found this method to be very fast and efficient.